# window.location stored to a variable causing errors

Tags: javascript

consider the following javascript

```
var str=window.location;
newArray=str.split('/');
document.write(newArray[0]);
```

When I execute split on "var url"  which holds "window.location"  it is causing this error in firebug console

```
TypeError
arguments: Array[2]
message: "—"
stack: "—"
type: "undefined_method"
__proto__: Error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the **string** that contains the url.

```
window.location.href
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location` is an object.  If you want just the URL, use `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location` is an `Object` (so it has no `split()` method). `split()` is a method of a `String`.

You need to use `window.location.href` or `window.location.toString()` (or use it in a `String` context so its coerced to a `String`).

You may also be wanting to split on the path only, in which case you should use `location.pathname`. You can then use `substr(1)` to drop the leading `/` (which would only split to an empty string anyway with `split('/')`).